# Buffer overrun attack

Tags: c, assembly, buffer, overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSIZE 30

char grade = '3';
char Name[BUFSIZE];

void readString(char *s) {
char buf[BUFSIZE];
int i = 0; 
int c;

while (1) {
  c = fgetc(stdin);
  if ((c == EOF) || (c == '\n')) 
     break;
  buf[i++] = c;
}
buf[i] = 0;

for (i = 0; i < BUFSIZE; i++) 
  s[i] = buf[i];

return;
}

int main(void) {
  mprotect((void*)((unsigned int)Name & 0xfffff000), 1,
         PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);

  printf("What is your name?\n");
  readString(Name);

    if (strcmp(Name, "smart guy") == 0) 
     grade = '6';

    printf("Thank you, %s.\n", Name);
    printf("I recommend that you get a grade of %c on this  assignment.\n", 
         grade);

 exit(0);
  }
```

I am trying to overrun the buffer of the grade by giving a random name except of course "smart guy" and make it give me 6.Also i am trying to give it again a random name and give 9 can you help me how could this be possible.I was trying with some assembly on the buffer but it wasnt so successful

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You could take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to have a global idea of how this site works, and read the [advice on how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in the help center to see what questions are welcomed here and which are not.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that global variables aren't laid out like local variables? Have you tried making the variables local? Changing the order of definition? What input do you give? What output would you expect from that input, and what output do you actually get?

Comment: I am not allowed to change the code i have to buffer overflow as it is.

Comment: Then you need to be able to look at the generated assembly, look at the data segments of the executable file, and learn how the compiler you're building the program lays out global variables and where.

Comment: i am trying while executing the program giving it input of assembly or machine code getting the results that i am asking above.

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers have a memory map file that you can check after compilation. Specifically, check to see the address of variables grade and array buf. If variable *grade* is assigned an address earlier than the address for array *buf*, then value of *grade* will not change if array *buf* is overrun.

Comment: i was trying to make the return address of readstring(Name); instead of checking the if going to grade='6';